# If a line ends with =, append the next line to it (sed)

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have some trouble with use this regex correct (in bash).

If a line in a text-file ends with =, it should append the next line to it.

I tried it with:  sed -e :a -e '/\$/N; s/=\n//; ta'

But this way it doesn't work, anyone that could help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a compliant QP decoder in the first place?

Comment: Didn't know about QP, but that's it! Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: You were close: `sed ':a; /=$/ {N; s/=\n//; ba}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With perl you could do:

```
perl -pe 's/=\n/=/g' inputfile
```

Sample input:

```
line1                                                                           
line2=                                                                          
line3                                                                           
line4=                                                                          
line5=                                                                          
line6
```

Output:

```
line1
line2=line3
line4=line5=line6
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/=\n/=/;ta;P;D' file
```

Keep at most two lines in the pattern space and if the first ends in `=`, join it with the second and repeat.